# Does this 2x4 brick exist?

Tags: piece-information, history

I've been working on a little history project to make a shadowbox/display-type thing of all of the major evolutions of the 2x4 brick over the years.  (I know this can get really in-depth, and I'm trying to hit major changes only, to preserve my sanity).

My question is this:
is there such a thing as a 2x4 brick (it would be ABS) with the "Pat Pend" obscured (covered by a blob, denoting an updated mold), that has **tubes only**?

In other words--**no braces, horizontal crossbars, ridges of any kind** (no slotted tubes either), just like a 60's brick, but made **late** enough to have the "Pat Pending" obscured, but **early** enough to not have any added reinforcements.

Also, by all of this I mean a brick that would have been in normal sets, and not a sample or test brick.

It's getting frustrating, and I wonder if I have invented this category!

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a brick you have; a picture would be nice in that case.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to find out if there's such a thing. One site lists something that sounds like it, but in the photo you can't see inside the brick!  (Leggodt.nl Unless I am reading it wrong.)

Comment: The entry I am referring to is #25 on this list of 2x4 variations.  In the second photo, you can see the "Pat Pend" is obscured, but you can't exactly see if there's a cross-bar running through the tubes! (He says "without cross support" which I am taking to mean the sidewalls in the modern 2x4 brick:                                                                                        http://www.leggodt.nl/items/lego/part.php?group=4&sq=25&language=en

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Yes. There is.

I have a few. They are really bad for connecting to things.

Like, BanBao bad. I can't really use them for anything.

But they do have the blobs.

So yes, there are those, and they are rare, for the same reason the "Pat Pending" ones are rare, mostly the age, and short transition period.

Comment: THANK YOU.  Of course, trying to find them on Bricklink is a nightmare.  Can you direct me to somewhere I could buy a red one?

Comment: Umm. I think... I could mail you one... If I can ever find it.

Comment: Please drop me a line if you do!

Comment: Since you're new, I would like to direct you to the little check-mark on the side of the question, which indicates that this answer is the accepted one. Also the up-arrow is an up-vote button, to indicate you like the answer. But only if you do.

Comment: Caleb, can you or anybody confirm for me that what we've been talking about has no crossbar (I've seen it called a "flowrib" also, the horizontal ridge inside the brick that goes through the center of the tubes).  In other words, it would look like this, but would have the PAT PENDING obscured:   https://www.flickr.com/photos/111441268@N03/21832397930/in/album-72157648936541745/  I can't find a photo anywhere.  Transition bricks I can understand; test bricks I don't think I'm going to get into...

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 5):

Leggodt.nl lists such a brick as part of their collection and also has photos of them. [Here](http://www.leggodt.nl/items/lego/part.php?group=4&sq=25) is the entry, and [on this site](http://www.leggodt.nl/items/lego/date-parts.php?language=nl) you can find a good picture showing the brick and the obscured *Pat. pend.:*

[image: Picture of plain brick with “patent pending” obscured]

(The entire site is a good source for what does exist.)